# Solutions of equation with floor function.

Tags: number-theory

Let $x, a$ be natural numbers. Let $C(a,x)=\{k\in\mathbb{N}:\lfloor\frac{x}{k}\rfloor=a \}$

> Find $|C(a,x)|$.

I tried to use following inequalities.

$\frac{x-k}{k}<a<\frac{x}{k}$

But it does not work.

I hope for help.

Regards.

Comment: if $a>x$ then can you tell  $|C(a,x)|$?

Comment: If $x\equiv 0 ~\text{mod}~a$ then? and if  $x\equiv c~\text{mod}~a$ where $c>0$ then ?

Answer (score 1):

if $\lfloor\frac xk\rfloor = a$, then $ a \le \frac xk < a + 1$. So $$\frac ax \le \frac 1k < \frac {a+1}x$$ and $$\frac x{a+1} < k \le \frac xa$$